# strangeness , psql use trim() and replace() Can't remove spaces

Tags: postgresql

Is it a format encoding problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vVzP.png)

```
select length(replace('  1221A7', ' ', '')),
       length(replace('　1221A7', ' ', '')),
       btrim('　1221A7'),length(btrim('　1221A7'));
```

Comment: The first two values are not *exactly* the same - but it is hard to tell what whitespace characters are by looking at them...

Comment: Do not use images for textual information. Copy and paste the text as update to question.

Comment: You could try `regexp_replace(..., '\s+', '', 'g')`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Hex view]

Save this and check under hex editor.
It looks like in second string there is 0x80 instead of 0x20